# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called by UITableViewController from framework

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, frameworks, didselectrowatindexpath

I created a framework which contains a `UITableViewController`. For some reason, when I use this framework and create this VC, it loads perfectly and the datasource methods work great and it looks just like it should. However, absolutely nothing happens when I click on the cells. I know that it should work because when I use this VC NOT in the framework, it works fine.

I just have `NSLog` statements set for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but they aren't called at all. Why would using this VC from a framework make `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` not be called?

Edit: I discovered the issue has something to do with the SlidingNavigationController I am using.

Specifically, if I use the following code in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, then everything works fine:

```
 NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Lights" ofType:@"bundle"];
    NSBundle *lights = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:lights];
    SlideNavigationController *nc = (SlideNavigationController*)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SlideNavigationController"];
    ViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

    MenuViewController * _mvc = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle: lights];
    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = _mvc;
    [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightMenu = vc;
    self.window.rootViewController = nc;
```

However, if I use that SAME code anywhere else in my project (for example, a button in a `VC` that launches this `storyboard` sequence), the `TableView` is not responsive.

What is so special about putting that code in `didFinishLaunching`?

Comment: Are you creating the `tableview` programatically? could u please share some code?

Comment: Do you confirm the UITableViewDelegate Protocol?

Comment: @casillas @ Md.Muzahidul Islam -- just added the code

Comment: Is your `tableView` stored in `MenuViewController` right? If so where are your `UITableViewDelegate` methods implemented?

Comment: The delegate methods are in MenuViewController. It is the delegate.

Comment: I just added some edits -- should make the issue more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my answer is if your `UITableViewDelegate` methods are implemented in `MenuViewController`, then remove your below code.

<strike>leftMenu.tableView.delegate = self;</strike>

and inside of your `MenuViewController` tell your `tableView` that `self` is delegate, like:

```
// in MenuViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that has already been done. I believe I have limited the problem down to SlideNavigationController -- when I use a regular NC, this problem doesn't happen.

Comment: Then show your `SlideNavigationController`'s implementation. How is it implemented?

Comment: Any chance you accidentally typed `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?